# How to perform query in MongoDB, through Doctrine 2 ODM using PHP on Zend Framework2?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

> I've attached sample code here. The query returns the entire db's
>   mapping instead of the data being queried for, or an error with the
>   Abstract-Hydrator class.
>
> Here's the code for the mapper:-

```
    <?php


    namespace HelpostApi\Document;
    use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

    /** @ODM\Document(collection="posts") */

    class Post
    {

    /** @ODM\Id */
    private $id;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    private $postTitle;
    /**
    * @param field_type $postTitle
    */
    public function setPostTitle($postTitle)
    {
    $this->postTitle = $postTitle;
    }
    /**
    * @param field_type $postTitle
    */
    public function getPostTitle()
    {
    return $this->postTitle;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

> And here's the code for controller, incorporating the query function:-

```
    <?php 
    namespace HelpostApi\Controller;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
    use HelpostApi\Document\Post;

    class PostController extends AbstractRestfulController {
    public function getList() 
    {
    $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
    print_r( $dm->createQueryBuilder('HelpostApi\Document\Post')
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult()
    ->execute()
    );
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Check out the [examples in the documentation](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#getting-single-result), you will need to remove the `execute()` if using `getSingleResult()`. Also the returned result from the query builder, in the case of `getSingleResult`, should be a single `Post` entity or `NULL`. If you have more than one result a  `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Cursor` - Dumping this to the screen wouldn't be very helpful, it's meant to be iterated.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is simple you may prefer to use one of the built in ODM methods:

```
$this->dm->getRepository('HelpostApi\Document\Post')->find($id);
```

or

```
$criteria=array('key'=>'value');
$this->dm->getRepository('HelpostApi\Document\Post')->findOneBy($criteria);
```

Each will return either a single HelpostApi\Document\Post object or NULL.